# Relation between Lefschetz number and the degree of a map on the sphere

Tags: differential-topology

I would like to check that the Lefschetz number $\Lambda_f$ and the degree $deg_f$ of a smooth mapping $f:\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ satisfy
$$\Lambda_f-deg_f=1$$
but I am clueless. I know that since $\mathbb{S}^2$ is compact, connected and orientable manifold then the following equations hold
$$deg(f)=\sum_{x\in f^{-1}(p)} sign\ df(x)$$
$$\Lambda_f=\sum_{x\text{ fixed point}} sign(df(x)-I)$$
where $p$is a regular value for $f$ and $f$ is a Lefschetz mapping. I guess they may be useful for this purpose, but I cannot relate them to get to the desired equation.

Comment: This will be far, far easier with the homological definition of Lefschetz number and degree.  It is a less-than-one-line argument.

Comment: P.S. You've also omitted important hypotheses here: $p$ is a regular value of $f$, and $f$ is has only Lefschetz fixed points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and remarks! What would be a possible path using these "Linear Algebra" formulas? I would like to know how complicated it is supposed to be if not following your suggestion

Comment: I don’t see anything obvious. This is very special to $S^2$. So you can reduce to $\Bbb R^2$. Where did this come from?

Comment: From these lecture notes: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/difftop.pdf

Comment: Exercise 4.4.15

Comment: Note they do have the (co)homological definition here as well. That is their intent.